# Spring Security блокирует все запросы. Код ответа 401

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-security

Разрабатываю Spring приложение, реализующее rest api.
У меня возникли проблемы после создания файла конфигурации spring security.

*src/main/resources/config/CustomSecurityConfiguration.kt:*

```
package config

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain


@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun userDetailsService(bCryptPasswordEncoder: BCryptPasswordEncoder?): UserDetailsService? {
        val manager = InMemoryUserDetailsManager()
        if (bCryptPasswordEncoder != null) {
            manager.createUser(
                User.withUsername("user")
                    .password(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("userPass"))
                    .roles("USER")
                    .build()
            )
        }
        if (bCryptPasswordEncoder != null) {
            manager.createUser(
                User.withUsername("admin")
                    .password(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("adminPass"))
                    .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
                    .build()
            )
        }
        return manager
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun authManager(
        http: HttpSecurity,
        bCryptPasswordEncoder: BCryptPasswordEncoder?,
        userDetailService: UserDetailsService?
    ): AuthenticationManager? {
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder::class.java)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService(bCryptPasswordEncoder))
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)
            .and()
            .build()
    }


    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain? {
        http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE)
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**")
            .hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**")
            .hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/signup")
            .anonymous()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors()
        return http.build()
    }

}
```

Теперь на каждый мой запрос я получаю ответ с кодом 401, что логично.
Однако, когда я перехожу по роуту для регистрации (/api/auth/signup) я так же получаю 401 не смотря на то, что к этому роуту применяется permitAll().
После этого я заменил `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/signup").permitAll()` на `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()`. Я ожидал что теперь любые запросы, по роутам начинающиеся на /, будут разрешены... Но, увы, я снова увидел код 401.

Проблема кажется тривиальной, но к сожалению, моих знаний Spring и Kotlin/Java не хватает для ее решения((

*src/main/resources/application.yml*

```yml
server:
  port: 1232

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/kissing_company
    username: admin
    password: admin
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    database: postgresql
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate.format_sql: true
      hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation: true
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/changelog.yml
    enabled: false

security:
  enable:
      csrf: false

logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        security: DEBUG
```

Буду благодарен, если кто-то поможет.

[Ссылка на проект](https://github.com/Machalkas/kissing_company/blob/fuck/spring-authorization/src/main/resources/config/CustomSecurityConfiguration.kt)

Пример запроса: `curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:1232/signup' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --data-raw '{ "username": "user1", "fname": "Николь", "sname": "Дэниелс", "password": "123" }'`

Comment: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter - Deprecated. попробуй тут почитать [Spring Security: Upgrading the Deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Comment: @стасевич, спасибо за ответ! Попробовал, не помогло( Добавил в конец вопроса ссылку на проект. Мне кажется проблема может быть вообще не в файле CustomSecurityConfiguration.kt, но учитывая мой уровень понимания Spring и Kotlin я могу проблему в упор не видеть. Пример отправляемого мной запроса ```curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:1232/signup' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username": "defka3",
    "fname": "Николь",
    "sname": "Дэниелс",
    "password": "123"
}'```